# doctrine tell query builder to prevent lazy loading

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entities `Product` and `Provider`, one product can have multiple providers, so between product and provider I have one to many relation

`Product`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    public string $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Provider",
     *     mappedBy="product",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
     *     orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    public Collection $providers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->providers = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and `Provider`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Provider
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    public bool $available;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="providers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    public Product $product;
}
```

and I need to get product by id and all his availiable providers, to do so I have a repository and query like this:

```
class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Product::class);
    }

    public function getProductWithActionProviders(int $productId): Product
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
          ->innerJoin('product.providers', 'pp')
          ->addSelect('pp');
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('pp.available', ':true'))
          ->setParameter('true', true, Types::BOOLEAN);
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('product.id', ':productId'))
          ->setParameter('blueprintId', $productId, Types::INTEGER);

         return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

and as a result it still returning all providers no matter if it's available or not, I'm not quite sure but I think it's due to lazy loading and internal query returning only available providers, but when I'm making call to entity to get providers, it lazy load all not fetched providers??? Here is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT p0_.id                        AS id_0,
       p0_.name                      AS name_1,
       p1_.id                        AS id_11,
       p2_.available                 AS available_19,
FROM products b0_
         INNER JOIN providers p1_ ON p1_.product_id = p0_.id
WHERE p1_.available = ?
  AND p0_.id = ?
```

How can I prevent of loading not needed providers??? I know I can set loading strategy to `Eager` in the entity in relations description, but I do not want to turn it of at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you set a `blueprintId` parameter. Copy past error?

You could simplify your code like this:

```
    public function getProductWithActionProviders(int $productId): Product
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
                   ->select('product', 'providers')
                   ->join('product.providers', 'providers')
                   ->where('providers.available = 1')
                   ->andWhere('product.id = :productId')
                   ->setParameter('productId', $productId)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getSingleResult();
    }
```

If your available parameter in database is a boolean, then you can use 0 or 1 in condition.

Comment: yep it's copy past error and question was not how to simplify query. I got my products and when I'm calling $product->providers it's making additional query and showing all providers including not available,  but I do not need unavailable providers

Comment: have you try ```->where('providers.available = 1')``` instead?